# Finding closest date to a specified date in sas dataset?

Tags: sas

Based on the data could anyone assist me - making a program that contains

test_date closest to delivery_date.

**delivery_date**       11/16/2011

**test_date**           21/nov/2011                10/nov/2011           5/oct/2010

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is incomplete.  Please edit it to explain the data structure.  It's not clear if these are two different datasets or one dataset, if the test_dates are in multiple rows or one row with three columns.  Are these date variables, or strings?  How do you want to handle ties?

Answer (score 0):

Can't really answer properly without more information, but if you have two datasets and one row per date, and actual date variables, then the solution is something like this:

```
create table finaldsn as 
 select a.* 
 , b.* 
 , a.delivery_date-b.test_date as days 
 , abs(calculated days) as absdays 
 , min(calculated absdays)as close 
 from dsnA as a 
 full join 
 dsnB as b 
 on a.subject=b.id 
 where a.delivery_date ne . and b.ltest_datebdt ne . 
and b.id in (select distinct subject 
 from dsnA) 
 group by a.subject, a.delivery_date 
 having calculated absdays=calculated close 
;
quit;
```

This is from the following paper: http://www.lexjansen.com/pharmasug/2003/coderscorner/cc001.pdf which also presents a few other solutions.

Comment: hey Joe the data is two separate sets with one date in the delivery_date variable of

Comment: Hey joe I dont really know how to include the data here but the idea is this. I have an excel file and in it there are two sheets one contains a single observation for delivery_date variable (11/16/2011) and the other sheet contains 20 observations for the test_date variable. My problem is how to do the calculation to find the closest test date to the delivery date. And how to match the one observation to the 20 for the test date variable. If you want to see the data Ill be happy to provide it. just let me know how. thank you!

Comment: All of that is what I assumed.  Please look at the answer and let me know if it works or if not, what you need help working out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SAS function INTCK to calculate the diference between a sample date and your target date, then you can just keep the date which is closer to 0.

here is a link so you can quickly pick up on this functions:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212868.htm

also, feel free to check out the other functions present on the left side of the link, as they can come in handy in the long run.

Comment: INTCK is for calculating interval differences, not naive differences.  SAS dates are stored as integer numbers of days, so a simple comparison is sufficient.  INTCK would just muddle things up.